# Where can I find sample code for Nucleo.NET?

Tags: .net, mvp

I've been researching MVP frameworks for .NET, and [Nucleo.NET](http://nucleo.codeplex.com/) looks very interesting. I have read (alright, *skimmed*) the documentation, but I find it a bit hard to get started.
Can anybody point me to any sample code or tutorial to get my feet wet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find several blog posts regarding the Nucleo framework (including some examples) on the project coordinator's blog.

http://msmvps.com/blogs/bmains/archive/tags/Nucleo/default.aspx

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

http://nucleo.codeplex.com/ is a reference to nucleo.net not sure if it is the same as what you want though

Comment: Yes, that is the framework I'm talking about. I couldn't find any concrete examples on its page, though.

Answer (score 0):

This project is new, not very popular. That's why there is no samples, tutorials. Try to understand yourself and then create your own sample code to help other people.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured. I'll post the results of my research, if any.